# Idempotents in group rings of finite cyclic groups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, group-rings

For which fields $K$ and integers $n>1$ does the group ring $K(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ have idempotents distinct from $0$ and $1$?

Comment: If $n \ne 0$ and $K$ has all $n$th roots of unity, then the Fourier transform identifies idempotents in $K(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$ with idempotents in $K^{\oplus\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z}$.  In particular, in this case, non-trivial idempotents exist if and only if $n > 1$.

Comment: Say $n\ge 1$. This $K$-algebra is $K[t]/(t^n-1)$. So there's an idempotent as soon as $(t^n-1)$ has two distinct irreducible factors. In char. 0 this is true iff $n\ge 2$. In char $p$ this is true iff $n$ is not a power of $p$. Is it an exercise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, when $G$ is a finite group and $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, the group algebra $\mathbb{K}G$ has no non-trivial idempotent if and only if the regular $\mathbb{K}G$-module is indecomposable. If $G$ is non-trivial and the characteristic of $\mathbb{K}$ is either zero or is coprime to $|G|$, then this is never the case, since the augmentation ideal is a direct summand of the regular module in that situation.

If $|G|$ is divisible by the characteristic of $\mathbb{K}$, say $p$, then either $G$ is a $p$-group, in which case the regular $\mathbb{K}G$-module is indecomposable (eg by a theorem of J.A. Green), or else $|G|$ is divisible by some prime $q \neq p,$ in which case $G$ has a conjugacy class of elements of order $q$, and the projective cover of the trivial $\mathbb{K}G$-module has dimension at most $\frac{|G|}{q},$ so that  $\mathbb{K}G$ contains an idempotent which is neither zero nor $1$.

Hence when $\mathbb{K}$ has prime characteristic $p$ and $G$ is a finite group, the group algebra $\mathbb{K}G$ has an idempotent other than $0$ or $1$ if and only if $G$ is not a $p$-group, while if $\mathbb{K}$ has characteristic zero and $G$ is a non-trivial finite group, then  $\mathbb{K}G$ always has idempotents other than $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I think the first assertion is correct with "central idempotent". Indeed there might be non-central idempotents in $KG$ even with $KG$ indecomposable. It is true that for  a $p$-group $G$ and $K$ of characteristic $p$, $KG$ has no nontrivial idempotent?

Comment: @YCor : The group algebra $\mathbb{K}G$ is indecomposable as $G \times G$- module if and only if there is no non-trivial central dempotent of $\mathbb{K}G$. My first statement above refers to $\mathbb{K}G$ as right $\mathbb{K}G$-module.

Comment: @YCor : Yes, it is true that when $\mathbb{K}$ has characteristic $p$ and $G$ is a finite $p$-group, then $\mathbb{K}G$ has no non-trivial idempotent.  For any finite group $G$, the existence of a non-trivial idempotent $e$ of $\mathbb{K}G$ yields a direct sum decomposition of $\mathbb{K}G$ as right $\mathbb{K}G$-module ( that is, $\mathbb{K}G = e \mathbb{K}G \oplus (1-e)\mathbb{K}G$).

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying my confusion!

Comment: @Geoff Robinson Thank you very much for your answer! Is there any paper or book which answers my question so that I can cite it?

Comment: The result you want is a very special instance of more general theory.  I am not sure of a reference which would give this special case as  a result in its own right ( thought it might appear in the exercises in some cases).